# Проверка чекбоксов с одним классом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. В jQuery новичок. 
Хочу сделать (наглядный пример):
http://gyazo.com/d9ba4126728a498a2fa622edc94736fb.png?1367061508

Сейчас имею такой код:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]#vibrat_vse_tovari_check_2').change(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){ 
$('.dobavit_v_korzinu_vibr_tovari').addClass("active_cart_but_bolsh");
$(".dobavit_v_korzinu_vibr_tovari").prop('disabled', false);
}
  else {
$(".dobavit_v_korzinu_vibr_tovari").prop('disabled', true);
$('.dobavit_v_korzinu_vibr_tovari').removeClass ('active_cart_but_bolsh');
  }
 });
```

Проблема в том, что снятие любого чекбокса делает кнопку неактивной, а нужно, что бы кнопка была активной, пока не будет снят любой последний чекбокс.

Есть еще подобный код, но работает так же как и верхний:

```
$(".rtyrtyrtyrty").change(function () {
if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
$('.dobavit_v_korzinu_vibr_tovari').addClass("active_cart_but_bolsh");
$(".dobavit_v_korzinu_vibr_tovari").prop('disabled', false);
} else {
$(".dobavit_v_korzinu_vibr_tovari").prop('disabled', true);
$('.dobavit_v_korzinu_vibr_tovari').removeClass ('active_cart_but_bolsh');
}
});
```

Не могу сообразить, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример решения на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2wJn/).

Comment: Уже помогли, но все равно, большое спасибо, что откликнулись!)

Answer (score 0):

[Еще один вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/4GhdJ/), для нескольких групп checkbox-ов

Comment: Спасибо Вам)